# OpenGL related header not found after upgrade to Mac OX El Captitan

Tags: macos, opengl

I just recently upgraded to El Captitan. After the upgrade, the OpenGL related headers, like `<OpenGL/gl.h>`, can not be found. The problem does not exist before the upgrade. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You'll probably need an Xcode update to get the matching platform SDK for the new OS.

Comment: I also upgraded XCode to version 7.0 (7A220)

Comment: I found the OpenGL headers can be found with XCode. I am using QtCreator as the IDE and g++-mp-4.8 instaledl with MacPorts as the compiler.

Comment: I don't know where those tools/environments look for the OpenGL headers. My answer here explains where the headers are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197223/where-are-the-opengl-header-files-located-on-macosx/23576954#23576954.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is because the Mac SDK version is not correctly set in Qt after system upgrade.
One can follow the asnswer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8) to change the mac os version to correct one.

But there is still one problem remaining, the compiler is not able to find the OpenGL framework when linking the executables. I found it is because the linker option `-Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk`, which is automatically added by qmake. If I manually type it the linking command without the option, then it works. I haven't found out how to solve this problem yet.