# macOS command line compile g++ OpenGL ES .cpp file

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, opengl-es

`my.cpp` file has `#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>`. I am trying to compile it by `g++ -c my.cpp` which fails with `fatal error: 'OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h' file not found #import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>`

I am able to compile it from Xcode with `GLKit.framework`. How to compile it in macOS from command line?

**--EDIT--**

[Where are the OpenGL header files located on MacOSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197223/where-are-the-opengl-header-files-located-on-macosx#answer-2197234) seems relevant but it is to `OpenGL`. I am looking for `OpenGL ES`

The include path shown by Xcode is

[image]

but I couldn't figure out its location in the file system to use with compiler's `-I` option

Comment: Is `OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h` in a place the compiler will look for?  Some good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344317/where-does-gcc-look-for-c-and-c-header-files

Comment: Don't know the path of it. I have edited the question regarding it

Comment: I think you can pass the name of the framework to it also `-framework OpenGLES`...

Comment: `clang: warning: -framework OpenGLES: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`
`In file included from my.cpp:9:`
`./my.hpp:13:9: fatal error: 'OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h' file not found`
`#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving would be specifying the `OpenGLES` location:

```
g++ -c my.cpp -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhon‌​eOS.platform/Develop‌​er/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3‌​.sdk/System/Library/‌​Frameworks -framework OpenGLES
```

> The `-F` flag indicates the library location, and `-framework`
>   indicates which framework to use.

Technically `-isysroot` could work as well:

```
g++ -c my.cpp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhon‌​eOS.platform/Develop‌​er/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3‌​.sdk
```

Comment: thats what I am looking for.